# How many six bit strings contain exactly one 0?

Tags: combinatorics

So I was doing my combinations homework when I stumbled upon this question. My teacher didn't teach us that and I'm a 10th Grader. So can anyone kindly answer my question? Thanks!

Comment: Well, a six bit string with exactly one 0 looks something like this
$$
110111
$$
Now, you can "move the zero around" ... In how many ways can you place the zero?

Comment: Can you write them all down? You may start to spot a pattern. And people on this site like it when they can see you have put in some effort yourself first

Comment: "*...my* **combinations** *homework...*"  That should give you a huge hint as to how to proceed already.  The end result is that the number of length $n$ bit-strings which contain exactly $k$ 0's is $\binom{n}{k}$, the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) "$n$ choose $k$".

Comment: You need a clarification on whether the "leading", i.e. most significant bit, can be a zero. I would probably answer with the assumption of 'yes' but add a small note to cover the case when the leading bit has to be a one.

Answer (score 2):

We want find the number of six bit strings contain exactly one $0$.

It is a linear arrangement of five $1$ and one $0$. Hence, there are
$$\frac{6!}{5!1!}=6$$
strings.